# Where to ask design rationale, architectural choices and "when should I use" type of questions about Software Engineering?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have some questions about programming paradigms, design choices, and why I should want to use X when I could also do it using Y.

Here are some examples:

- Why should I use `Async` instead of spawning a new thread to do the
  job?
- Should I use for a relational database, an in-memory database, or a
  specific built-in data structure to process a set of objects X times?
- Why should I use a thread pool instead of using a for loop to spawn X
  number of threads?

These kinds of questions are only possible to answer by referring to concepts, internal workings, using pseudo code, or telling personal experiences (I used to use A for a number of years, but it failed in case B).

I feel that they are not suitable for Stack Overflow, because it looks more a place to find solutions to practical problems. I also think that these kinds of questions would be instantly downvoted and marked as *too broad* or *opinion based*.

These are more on the *academic side* of software engineering and development, so I guess [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to ask them, but I wasn't sure.

I didn't want to add chaos to either communities and make unnecessary work for moderators by asking unrelated questions, and that's why I'm asking here.
Could you please help me figure it out?

Comment: see also: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/165773)

Answer (score 1):

If you think that [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is the correct site, and you still think that after taking their [Tour](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) and reviewing their [on-topic page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), then I think the thing to do is to join that site and ask your first question there.

If you have not understood the scope of the site, then the worst that should happen is that you may receive some down and/or close votes, hopefully with some comments as to why, when they see your 1 rep and check your profile to see that you are new.

I recommend treating every downvote, close vote and comment as an opportunity to learn more about the type of questions that are well received on a site.

Comment: Lurking may also be a suitable way...